# What is the ECL equivalent of NaN or IsNumeric?

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

I want to check if some value (i.e: 42 or 41.0005) is a number in ECL (HPCC).
I have in mind a function using Regular Expressions like this:

```
EXPORT IsNumeric(STRING UniqueID) := FUNCTION
        regex:='^\\d+$';       
        RETURN REGEXFIND(regex, UniqueID);    
END;
```

**Is there a built-in IsNumeric function?**

If not... **Is there any better way of doing it than using regex**? (Thinking both in readability and performance)

- Maybe an ECL command?
- STD function?
- Casting?
- #GetDataType?
- str.filter?

NOTE: Seems that in [old versions of HPCC](https://hpccsystems.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=192&p=7a49&hilit=isnumeric#p749) (2011) such function did not exist. But many releases have happened since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [asked](https://hpccsystems.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3093&p=13023#p13023) if official HPCC forums and **there is NO native IsNumeric function in ECL**.

In the answers there are several nice ECL workarounds better than mine. The best seems to be:

```
IsNumeric(STRING n) := n = (STRING)(DECIMAL)n;
```